# Image upload not working Always get the FALSE value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

UI [image: ui]
Image upload part is not working, I want to upload image path in Database but not working, and not bind correctly can't save it, can you please help me,  Table to displayed upload image value is always **FALSE** [image]
**ASPX**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  ID="fileupload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Uploaded Images/Default.png" runat="server" ID="image"  Width="40" Height="40"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**CODE**

```
     #region Detail Save1
        private DataTable CreateDetailSave()
        {
            DataTable dtDetailSave1 = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc1;
            dc1 = new DataColumn("intArticleDetailId");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dc1 = new DataColumn("intSectionId");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dc1 = new DataColumn("intCompoundId");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);            
            dc1 = new DataColumn("decSectionWeight");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dc1 = new DataColumn("intMessageId");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dc1 = new DataColumn("strImage");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvArticle.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dr = dtDetailSave1.NewRow();

                Label lblintArticleDetailId = (Label)row.FindControl("lblArticleDetailId");
                Label lblSectionId = (Label)row.FindControl("lblSectionId");
                DropDownList ddlCompound = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlCompoundId");
                TextBox txtdecSectionWeighte = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtdecSectionWeighte");
                DropDownList intMessage = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlMessage");

                FileUpload fileupload = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("fileupload");

                dr["intArticleDetailId"] = CurrentMode == "Add" ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(lblintArticleDetailId.Text);

                dr["intSectionId"] = Convert.ToInt32(lblSectionId.Text);
                dr["intCompoundId"] = ddlCompound.SelectedValue;
                dr["decSectionWeight"] = txtdecSectionWeighte.Text.Trim() != "" ? Convert.ToDecimal(txtdecSectionWeighte.Text.Trim()) : 0;
                dr["intMessageId"] = intMessage.SelectedValue;
                dr["strImage"] = fileupload.HasFile;

                dtDetailSave1.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dtDetailSave1;
        }
        #endregion

         #region pageload
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                ClearControls();

                FillArticleDetails();

                EnableControls(false);
                Session["SearchPopup"] = false;

            }
            else
            {
                if (Session["SearchPopup"] != null)
                {
                    SearchPopup = (bool)(Session["SearchPopup"]);
                    if (SearchPopup != false)
                    {
                        MyMPE.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MyMPE.Hide();
                    }
                }

                vAdSearchParaList = new List<SearchParametors>();

            }
        }
        #endregion
 #region Create Article table
        private void createArticleDataTable()
        {
            if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("intArticleDetailId", typeof(int)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("intSectionId", typeof(int)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("strSectionName", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("intCompoundId", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("decSectionWeight", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("intMessageId", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("fileupload", typeof(string)));

            }

            gvArticle.DataSource = dt;
            gvArticle.DataBind();
        }        
        #endregion

        #region Compound Grid - Add empty row
        private void ArticleGridAddEmptyRow(int newId)
        {
            DataRow newDr = null;
            newDr = dt.NewRow();
            newDr["intArticleDetailId"] = 1;
            newDr["intSectionId"] = 1;
            newDr["strSectionName"] = "";
            newDr["intCompoundId"] = "";
            newDr["decSectionWeight"] = "";
            newDr["intMessageId"] = "";
            newDr["strImage"] = "";

            dt.Rows.Add(newDr);

            if (dtArticleDetails == null || dtArticleDetails.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                dtArticleDetails = dt;
            }
            else
            {
                dtArticleDetails.Merge(dt);

                gvArticle.DataSource = dt;
                gvArticle.DataBind();
            }
        }
        #endregion

protected void gvArticle_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gvArticle.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            FileUpload fu = row.Cells[0].FindControl("strImage") as FileUpload;
            if (fu != null && fu.HasFile)
            {
                fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded Images" + fu.FileName));
            }
        }
```

---

**full aspx**

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvArticle" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="15" OnRowDataBound="gvArticle_RowDataBound" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" OnRowUpdating="gvArticle_RowUpdating">
                                                 <%--<HeaderStyle BackColor="#3d4247" ForeColor="White" />--%>
                                                            <Columns>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="intArticleDetail" Visible="false">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblArticleDetailId" Width="2" Text='<%# Bind("intArticleDetailId") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField> 

                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SectionID" Visible="false">
                                                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSectionId" Width="2" Text='<%# Bind("intSectionId") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
                                                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>                                                        

                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Section">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSectionName" Width="100"  Text='<%# Bind("strSectionName") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>  
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Compound">
                                                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblItemTypeEdit" Width="50" Text='<%# Bind("strCompoundName") %>' lientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">                                                                               
                                                                            </asp:Label>
                                                                        </EditItemTemplate>

                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompoundId" Width="200" CssClass="form-control my-DropDownThin" lientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">                                                                               
                                                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                 </asp:TemplateField>


                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weight">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdecSectionWeighte" Width="100%" Text='<%# Bind("decSectionWeight") %>' lientIDMode="Static" runat="server">  </asp:TextBox>                                                                            
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                                                <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Messagers">                                                                
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" Width="100%" Text='<%# Bind("intMessageId") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>--%>

                                                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Messagers">
                                                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessageId" Width="50" Text='<%# Bind("strMessage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">                                                                               
                                                                            </asp:Label>
                                                                        </EditItemTemplate>

                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMessage" Width="300" CssClass="form-control my-DropDownThin" lientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">                                                                               
                                                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                 </asp:TemplateField>

                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images">                                                                
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>


                                                              <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  ID="uploadFImage" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>

                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField> 


                                                                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">                                                                
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>


  <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Uploaded Images/Default.png" runat="server" ID="btnViewFImage"  Width="40" Height="40"/>

                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField> 

                                                            </Columns>

                                                 <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                                                 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                                 <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                                 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                                 <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                                                 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
                                                 <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                                                 <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />

                                            </asp:GridView>    
                                        </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>           
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvArticle"/> 
           </Triggers>

                                    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

---

**gvArticle_rowdatabound**

```
protected void gvArticle_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {


            }
            else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {


                { 


                }

                DataTable CompoundCode = clsArticle.CompoundDataForGrid("");

                DropDownList ddlCompoundId = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCompoundId");
                if (ddlCompoundId != null)
                {
                    ddlCompoundId.DataTextField = "Compound Code";
                    ddlCompoundId.DataValueField = "Compound Id";
                    ddlCompoundId.DataSource = CompoundCode;
                    ddlCompoundId.DataBind();

                    string country = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlCompoundId") as DropDownList).Text;
                    ddlCompoundId.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
                }


                DataTable MsgCode = clsArticle.MessageDataForGrid("");

                DropDownList ddlMessage = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlMessage");
                if (ddlMessage != null)
                {
                    ddlMessage.DataTextField = "Message Name";
                    ddlMessage.DataValueField = "Message Id";
                    ddlMessage.DataSource = MsgCode;
                    ddlMessage.DataBind();

                    ddlMessage.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
                    string country = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlMessage") as DropDownList).Text;
                    ddlMessage.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
                }



                //}


            }
        }
```

Comment: Code in link: https://wklej.to/dFXXf

Comment: Sir, Im add this, im upload the image and debug i got a my table following symbol ">"  im add the screen shot

Comment: Check this code `<asp:TextBox ID="txtstrImage" Width="100%" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" visible="False">  > </asp:TextBox>`. I can see it

Comment: This question needs some cleaning up. First of all, you should *really* clean up the code sections. It's *NOT* too much to ask of you to fix the markdown so that the code parts are actually sane on screen. Secondly, you screenshot shows that the debugger is in a method with a name starting with `sa`, presumably `saveArticle` or some such. But no such method is included in the question. How can we possibly give good answer if we have to guess what you code looks like?

Comment: Is it normal that you put the boolean value `HasFile` in the string value of your file ? (`dr["strImage"] = fileupload.HasFile;`)

Comment: is your `<form>` using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: no sir, sir , do you know how to create grid view upload

Comment: Look at the raw HTML in "View Source" (not your aspx controls). There will be at least one `<form>` tag in there. Does it have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has lots of issues. 
First of all `FileUpload` control doesn't have `AutoPostBack` property as well as `CommandArgument` property so you need a button in each row.

### .aspx fragment

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="upload">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="upload">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text="upload" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PK_FIELD") %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

### .aspx.cs fragment

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload fu = 
      ((GridViewRow)((WebControl)sender).NamingContainer)
          .FindControl("fileupload") as FileUpload;
    bool ok = false;
    if (fu != null && fu.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            //possible issue here.
            //process NEED PERMISSION to write to this folder
            //also some checks with fu.PostedFile are recommended
            fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + fu.FileName));
            ok = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ok = false;
        }
    }
    if (ok)
    {
        //update DB table and GridViewRow image field.
    }
}
```

I hope this explanation is useful and acceptable.

### Update based on your gridview

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvArticle" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CssClass="table
     table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="15" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvArticle_RowDataBound" 
 DataKeyNames="PK_field"  **important**
    >
        <%--<HeaderStyle BackColor="#3d4247" ForeColor="White" />--%>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="intArticleDetail" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblArticleDetailId" Width="2" 
Text='<%# Eval("intArticleDetailId") %>' **Bind is nonsense for label**
 runat="server"></asp:Label> **ClientIDMode="Static" remove everiwhere**
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SectionID" Visible="false">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSectionId" Width="2" Text='<%# Bind("intSectionId") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                                                        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Section">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSectionName" Width="100"  Text='<%# Bind("strSectionName") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Compound">
            <EditItemTemplate>** no edit mode remove**
                <asp:Label ID="lblItemTypeEdit" Width="50" 
Text='<%# Bind("strCompoundName") %>' ** see above**
ClientIDMode="Static" 
AutoPostBack="true" 
runat="server">                                                                               
                </asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompoundId" Width="200" 
    CssClass="form-control my-DropDownThin" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">                                                                               
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weight">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdecSectionWeighte" Width="100%" Text='<%# Bind("decSectionWeight") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">  </asp:TextBox>                                                                            
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Messagers">                                                                
    <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" Width="100%" Text='<%# Bind("intMessageId") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>--%>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Messagers">
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessageId" Width="50" Text='<%# Bind("strMessage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">                                                                               
    </asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMessage" Width="300" CssClass="form-control my-DropDownThin" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">                                                                               
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images">                                                                <ItemTemplate>
**work with upload. remove wrong attributes**
**AutoPostBack="True"CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" ** 
          <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="uploadFImage" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField> 
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">                                                                
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Uploaded Images/Default.png" runat="server" ID="btnViewFImage"  Width="40" Height="40"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField> 
</Columns>


     <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />

</asp:GridView>    
** place update button outside to update all columns **
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text="upload" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" runat="server" />

//.aspx.cs
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach(GridViewRow row in gvArticle.rows)
{

    FileUpload fu = 
          row.FindControl("fileupload") as FileUpload;
    bool ok = false;
    if (fu != null && fu.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            //possible issue here.
            //process NEED PERMISSION to write to this folder
            //also some checks with fu.PostedFile are recommended
            fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + fu.FileName));
            ok = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ok = false;
        }
    }
    if (ok)
    {
        //update DB table and GridViewRow image field.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sir, Not working , Im tired ,im try all of code but not work , anyway Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show error message? Also add `throw ex;` to `catch` block.

Comment: Start again. `FileUpload` doesn't have `AutoPostBack` and `CommandAttribute`. There is nothing in your code which can trigger postback. There is no switch to edit mode so `gvArticle_RowUpdating` is unreachable. And if *by miracle* you get there, your `FileUpload` is not in edit template.

Comment: how can i do it sir

Answer (score 2):

You try to save it with different path than the one you read: `Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded Images" + fu.FileName) != <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Uploaded Images/Default.png"` Notice missing / in the save path. Try this code:

```
protected void gvArticle_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = gvArticle.Rows[e.RowIndex];
   FileUpload fu = row.Cells[0].FindControl("strImage") as FileUpload;
   if (fu != null && fu.HasFile)
   {
       fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded Images/" + fu.FileName));

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When a file is selected using `FileUpload Control` ,then on `postback, PostedFile` property gets initialized with `HttpPostedFile` object for the file. Since `http request` cannot maintain state, so it looses it's state.

`FileUpload` control will not work with `asynchronous postback`.So a `postback` is needed to get the file. One way is to set the `triggers` for your `Upload` button

**TO PERSIST THE VALUE OF FILEUPLOAD CONTROL**, you can store the fileupload object altogether in `session` and after `postback` retrieve the values you require from session.

**EDIT :** Try with the following [example.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/261736/gridview-with-image-and-fileupload-controls-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: Sir Im try it always False

Comment: this object is null
` dr["strImage"] = fileupload.HasFile;` i think this is a problem HasFile

Comment: @PhantomAssassin Could you post the same code in page load and check if it has value?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `RowUpdating` so my suggestion is use `EditItemTemplate` along with `ItemTemplate` so Add this

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  ID="fileupload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

along with this:-

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  ID="fileupload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

So your `TemplateField` Image will look like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  ID="fileupload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  ID="fileupload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
   </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And for file upload as Lesmian said use this:-

```
protected void gvArticle_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gvArticle.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            FileUpload fu = row.Cells[0].FindControl("strImage") as FileUpload;
            if (fu != null && fu.HasFile)
            {
                fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded Images/" + fu.FileName));
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Im try this, not working sir, always get the path false

Comment: @PhantomAssassin can you paste your entire grid view html

Comment: @PhantomAssassin in your code you are binding your grid view `gvArticle` from where you are calling these function

Comment: Sir im  add the code , can you please check it, `fullaspx`

Comment: Sir , its in `gvArticle_RowUpdating`

Comment: can i paste my full cs file?

Comment: 1st thing is there is no edit button on your grid how you are editing your grid, have you tried to debug your code `gvArticle_RowUpdating` is firing or not?

Comment: sir, i have a NEW,UPDATE,SEARCH button , but not a grid view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114004/discussion-between-phantom-assassin-and-ansari).

Answer (score 2):

In aspx page use updatepanel control to hold the ID's that are generated.
refere the following code.

```
< asp:TemplateField HeaderText=""> 
  < ItemTemplate>              
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="fileUploadPanel">           
     <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  ID="fileupload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>
     </ContentTemplate>                                                             
     <Triggers>                                                             
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="fileupload" />    
    </Triggers>                                                 
  </asp:UpdatePanel>                                             
 </ItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>                                                 
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="ImageUploadPanel">  
  <ContentTemplate>                                         
    <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Uploaded Images/Default.png" runat="server" ID="image"  Width="40" Height="40"/>                       
  </ContentTemplate>                                    
  <Triggers>                                              
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="image" />            
 </Triggers>                                  
 </asp:UpdatePanel>                     
</ItemTemplate>                     
< /asp:TemplateField>
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

As @Ruban.J said "`FileUpload` control will not work with asynchronous postback"
means it always have some problem with `UpdatePanel`, Whenever a `Postback` occure `fileupload` lose it states [Its files],

He also said
**TO PERSIST THE VALUE OF FILEUPLOAD CONTROL**, you can store the fileupload object altogether in session and after postback retrieve the values you require from session.

so breaking all process into small steps

Step 1: You have to save all the `fileupload` object into session whenever postback occure, for this i think this should be work on pageLoad Event.

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Bind your gridview 1st time

            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<int, HttpPostedFile> postedFiles = new Dictionary<int, HttpPostedFile>();

                foreach (GridViewRow row in gvArticle.Rows)
                {

                    int id = Convert.ToInt16("YourUniqueRowId"); // whaterver your unique id is there
                    DropDownList ddlCompound = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlCompoundId");
                    // find your fileupload controll for that row         
                    FileUpload fileupload = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("fileupload");
                    if (fileupload.HasFile)
                    {
                        postedFiles.Add(id, fileupload.PostedFile);
                    }


                }
                Session["files"] = postedFiles;
            }
```

Also check whether you are getting file info here, by looking into each `HttpPostedFile`.

Step 2: whenever you need files just get it from session:

```
if (Session["files"] != null)
{
    Dictionary<int, HttpPostedFile> postedFiles = (Dictionary<int, HttpPostedFile>) Session["files"];
}
```

You can match Key value for deciding which file is for which row and save it to database.

Answer (score 2):

The given code has some serious mistakes and also it is not complete. It is really hard to reproduce at my end. Anyhow there are some thing that can be done to solve the problem:

- Remove unnecessary code like labels having contain `AutopostBack="true"`.
- `ClientIdMode="static"` in Gridview will produce invalid HTML and may be the cause of your problem, because it will produce HTML elements that have same id values and that will create invalid HTML page. There are various lines of code containing this attribute. Simply remove these.
- Third is your aspx code line `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvArticle"/>`. It should point to a button control that causes the postback after you have selected the image. I think, Here save button Id should be used.

Do the changes in your code and still it is not solved, you need to provide full page code for more diagnosis. 
Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You'll pretty much always get a boolean value (false) since you set the strImage value as such.

`dr["strImage"] = fileupload.HasFile;`

Check your code under the foreach.

Also, under the **`gvArticle_RowUpdating()`** event, you find for the fileupload control where with the value **`strImage`** instead of using your defined id **`fileupload`**.

```
protected void gvArticle_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gvArticle.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        FileUpload fu = row.Cells[0].FindControl("fileupload") as FileUpload;
        if (fu != null && fu.HasFile)
        {
            fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded Images" + fu.FileName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Codeone, do you bind the gridview on page_load? Also, the HasFile property is false, but how about the actual filedata? Is it null, or does it have a value?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `ClientIDMode = Inherit` in your `FileUpload` control and check it is work.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your `CreateDetailSave` method inside `foreach` loop you are saving your `filename` as `fileupload.Hasfile` which will always return true or false. That's why it is always returning false:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvArticle.Rows)
{
    dr["strImage"] = fileupload.filename;         //before it was fileupload.Hasfile
}
```

Comment: Sir, im try this after not get false values only get null